# How can I show the total value of a database in a label?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I have a database table called expenses. They are multiple columns such as food, gas, fuel etc all with numeric values. How can I generate the value of all the records added together and then to show the total in a label?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: SUM(yourField) is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean letting the database perform the sum for you. If that's the case then a query like this should do:

```
SELECT Food + Gas + Fuel AS Costs FROM Expenses
```

Should you want the total cost for all records? Then use `SUM`:

```
SELECT SUM(Food + Gas + Fuel) AS TotalCosts FROM Expenses
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice Yazan. I tried your query but it doesn't seem to add the total of the rows to the total_expenses row?

Comment: So you have total_expenses **column**? that wasn't mentioned in the question. Anyway, try this instead:
`UPDATE Expenses SET total_expenses = Food + Gas + Fuel`
Do a backup of your database before start manipulating with update commands.

Comment: This worked! Thank you @yazanpro, I appreciate it!

Comment: Sure. Glad to help.